# How do you say "plan documentaire" in english

Tags: translation

I need help translating the French term *plan documentaire*. Does anyone know a proper term in English for it ?

In my context, *plan documentaire* stands for the **list of documents** (of the project).

Comment: Mind telling us what the term means? A quick google search suggests that depending on context, it could mean *documents* or *documentation*, *documentary* (as in the type of film), and *plan-type documentaire* means *template*.

Comment: In my context, it stands for the list of the documents (of the project).

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question. And the answer is the project's *documentation*.

Comment: If , in fact, it means "list of documents", then why not use the translation "list of documents"?

Comment: List of document is translated as liste de documents in french. We don't use that term in french in my context so i guess the same goes for english.

Comment: If it is a list of documents cited or referred to in preparation, maybe 'References' or 'Bibliography'? But 'Report Structure' or something similar is another possibility. More context, please.

Answer (score 1):

If the documentation for a project is extensive, then it needs a **Table of Contents**.

The documentation itself might be called the *User Manual* -- but it depends.

If you provide a sentence with a blank where the desired phrase will go, it will be easier to find something that will work well for you.